# Can't install python 3.6.5

Tags: python, openssl, python-3.6, wget

I am trying to install python 3.6.5 from source and link it to openssl. This is my shell script:

```
# new openssl install
curl https://github.com/openssl/openssl/archive/OpenSSL_1_1_1a.zip | tar xz && cd OpenSSL_1_1_1a && ./config shared --prefix=/usr/local/ enable-weak-ssl-ciphers && make && make install

# Python install script
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib/"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/openssl"
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential checkinstall -y
apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev -y
cd /home/web/
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tgz | tar xzf Python-3.6.5.tgz && cd Python-3.6.5 
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ 
make install
```

When I try to run it from the Downloads using: `~/Downloads$ sudo bash custom_python.sh`

I get:

```
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Resolving www.python.org (www.python.org)... 151.101.16.223, 2a04:4e42:4::223
Connecting to www.python.org (www.python.org)|151.101.16.223|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.python.org's certificate, issued by ‘CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.python.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
custom_python.sh: line 13: ./configure: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

What is causing it? How to  solve it? 
I can open the python url provided in the wget normally from the browser.

Comment: Unlike `curl`, `wget` doesn't write the downloaded bytes to stdout by default. I think you want `&&` and not `|` between `wget` and `tar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another user has commented, `wget` does not write the data to stdout by default. There are two ways to fix your script:

```
wget -O- https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tgz | tar xzf Python-3.6.5.tgz && cd Python-3.6.5
```

In this case, you're making Wget output to `stdout`. However, I generally don't like this method. It is not a good idea to pipe things directly over the network. There are multiple safety and reliability issues.

Instead, you should do this:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tgz && tar xzf Python-3.6.5.tgz && cd Python-3.6.5
```

In the ideal scenario, you also check the signatures / checksums on the file you've downloaded to be sure that you don't have a corrupt archive